# Find maximum point out of n tasks

Tags: algorithm, task

Exact problem statement :

Given `N` tasks, find the maximal points that can be achieved by finishing them

**Problem Constraints**:

There are `T` minutes for completing `N` tasks

Solutions can be submitted at any time, including exactly `T` minutes after the start

`i`-th task submitted `t` minutes after the start, will get 
`maxPoints[i] - t * pointsPerMinute[i]` points

`i`-th task takes `requiredTime[i]` minutes to solve

**Input Format**

`Line 1`: `T`, total minutes available to finish

`Line 2`: Comma separated list of `maxPoints`

`Line 3`: Comma separated list of `pointsPerMinute`

`Line 4`: Comma separated list of `requiredTime`

**Sample Input**

```
75

250 500 1000

2 4 8

25 25 25
```

**Sample Output**

`1200`

Explanation

First, solve the third task `25` minutes after the start of the contest. Get `1000 - 8 * 25 = 800` points

Second, solve the second task `50` minutes after the start of the contest. Get `500 - 4 * 50 = 300` points

Third, solve the first task `75` minutes after the start of the contest. Get `250 - 2 * 75 = 100` points

In total, get `800 + 300 + 100 = 1200` points

I was able to get the solution by permuting and the calculating the point for each arrangement. I couldn't figure out optimized solution for this.

Comment: in genertal NP-hard problems, check [maximum flow algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem)

Comment: the exhaustive algorithm (checking all permutations) can be optimised by noting that some perumtations/arrangements are not-optimal from the start (or at least very early)

Answer (score 0):

I use greedy algorithm to solve this.

I use m for maxPoint, p for pointsPerMinute, r for requiredTime.

Consider finishing A task before B task, you can get:
Point(A, B) = m[A] - p[A] * r[A] + m[B] - p[B] * (r[A] + r[B])

Finishing B task before A task, you can get: 
Point(B, A) = m[B] - p[B] * r[B] + m[A] - p[A] * (r[A] + r[B])

If you should finish A task before B task, Point(A, B) need greater than Point(B, A), so Point(A, B) - Point(B, A) >= 0.

For some calculation, we can get:

r[A] / p[A] < r[B] / p[B].

That means, if we need to finish A task before B task, r[A] / p[A] should less than r[B] / p[B]. And we can sort all tasks by this and count the answer.

Comment: Thanks, nicely explained.

Comment: To your explanation I tried multiplying the ratio with the factor:
(maxPoint[A]/ requredTime[A]) * (r[A]/p[A]) and did sorting on this ratio

But for some test case it failed. Any idea if it can be done using greedy approach.

Comment: Hi, I guess it is a precision problem, so you can prevent the divide operator and using multiply instead. Such as

bool cmp(Task p, Task q) {
    return p.requireTime * q.pointPerMinute < q.requireTime * p.pointPerMinute
}

BTW: I think you have typo in your comments, because the order is not related to maxPoint.